# How to remove double Vary header nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to make sure that some of my responses will not be cached by anyone. 
One of the advised options is to set Vary: *.

Unfortunately my nginx which has enabled gzip support returns me two Vary headers if i add `add_header "Vary" "*";`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: nginx/1.11.1
 Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 14:56:16 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: keep-alive
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 Vary: Accept-Encoding
 Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
 Pragma: no-cache
 Expires: 0
 Vary: *
```

Any idea how to force having only `Vary: *` in responses and gzip support for the request on?

Comment: You have cache control set to no-cache and no-store which should prevent it from being cached already. Is this being ignored for some reason? The headers-more module has directives to add/remove headers: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module

Comment: There are some proxies or old browsers which have problems with that if Vary is not *

Comment: I see. Headers-more is probably you're best bet. Its included in nginx-extras if youre using debian/ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
gzip_vary off;
```

should stop gzip from auto-adding Vary header.

docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_vary